# How to get Gnome3 systray in Bionic?

Tags: gnome-shell

Long story short, I installed gnome-session and choose Gnome when login in GDM3. Disabled dash-to-dock. The UI now looks pretty much is Gnome3. But, I am not sure if this is something changed in Gnome3 itself, the bottom notification bar and systray (bottom left) are gone.

I am using topiconsplus to view the systray for now. But does not react to mouse click.

Comment: Yes, GNOME developers got rid of the "systray (bottom left) " (known as "legacy tray") since version 3.26 altogether.  Only way to show the icons is by using extensions like TopIcons plus or https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/

Comment: You can try to install GNOME FlashBack session (`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`) and check tray status in it.